# Selecting nth values in anonymous types

Tags: html-agility-pack, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types

I have a collection of HTML items after running an XPATH expression against an instance of HtmlDocument (HTMLAgilityPack).

The returning collection is:

The {h3} tag should be name of the item in my type, and the {div} should be the content, but I can't seem to figure out how to group these guys together?

My anon-type:

```
var nodes = xhtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='membInfo']/h3 | //div[@id='membInfo']/div");

(from node in nodes
 select new 
 {
    Name = node[j],
    Content = node[j + 1]
 });
```

Comment: Can you show one example? Possible input and desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var nodes = xhtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='membInfo']");

(from node in nodes
 select new 
 {
    Name = node.SelectSingleNode("./h3"),
    Content = node.SelectSingleNode("./div")
 });
```

The above code LINQ code will give you an anonymous type, where both `Name` and `Content` will be of type `HtmlNode`. You might want to take a look at the properties `Innertext`, `OuterHtml`, etc. depending on what you want to do next.